# Как рисовать сиволами псевдографики в консоли linux СИ

Tags: linux, c, gcc, консоль, ascii

вот на винде такую штуку делал (обычные символы Ascii кода)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а в линуксе псевдографики вообще нет чтоли?
написал такую вот фигню, и вместо знаков ромбы с вопросами

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
        {
            printf("%c", 177);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы в курсе что в линуксе используется юникод в терминале?

Comment: Ascii - это до 127

Comment: я поменял строку с выводм на printf("%c", 0x2593); и ничего не поменялось

Comment: `0x2593` - невалидное значение для паттерна `%c`, вам стоит попробовать печатать байты представляющие собой текст в кодировке utf-8. Ну или переключить эмулятор терминала на использование символов в той кодировке, которую вы использовали на Windows

Comment: @VTT я включил поддержку CP866  в настройках консоли. Стало лучше, но еперь консоль видимио некторые последовательности символов рушит. Напримр сообщение об ошибке теперь выглядит так  error: expected тАШ;тАЩ before тАШ}тАЩ token

Comment: очевидно, другие приложения пишет не в CP866

Comment: Пишите байты utf-8, которые соответствуют символам псевдографики в unicode (естественно, в используемом эмулятором терминала фонте данные глифы (изображения) должны присутствовать)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    // установить локаль, необходимо сделать дабы стандартные библиотеки знали,
    // в какую кодировку преобразовывать длинные символы при выводе
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

    // основной способ, должен быть переносимым и корректно работать 
    // при компиляции под любую систему (стандартным компилятором C99 или C11)
    // в локали который есть псевдографика
    printf("%lc", L'▒');
    // строго говоря, немного менее переносимый способ, привязанный к UNICODE
    printf("%lc", 0x2592);

    // не лучший способ, будет работать только если 8-битная кодировка файла совпадает
    // с кодировкой локали (на большинстве современных систем и то и другое — utf-8).
    printf("▒");

    return 0;
}
```

Также можно работать напрямую с широко-символьными потоками ввода-вывода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

    putwchar(L'▒');
    putwchar(0x2592);
    fputws(L"▒", stdout)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего найти нужные символы в таблице Unicode и выводить их в кодировке utf-8.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat t-utf.c && gcc t-utf.c && ./a.out
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  // Коды мастей в Unicode: 0x2660 ... 0x2667
  // 0010 0110  0110 0000
  // 0010011001100000
  // группируем биты по 6 для перевода в utf-8: 0010 011001 100000
  // utf-8: 11100010  10011001   10100000  0xe2 0x99 0xa0
  char *cardsuit[8] = {"\xe2\x99\xa0",  // 0x2660
               "\xe2\x99\xa1",
               "\xe2\x99\xa2",
               "\xe2\x99\xa3",
               "\xe2\x99\xa4",
               "\xe2\x99\xa5",
               "\xe2\x99\xa6",
               "\xe2\x99\xa7"  // 0x2667
  };

  puts("https://unicode-table.com/ru/#geometric-shapes");
  printf("карточные масти: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    printf("%s", cardsuit[i]);

  return puts("") == EOF;
}
https://unicode-table.com/ru/#geometric-shapes
карточные масти: ♠♡♢♣♤♥♦♧
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Кстати, если есть какие-то проблемы с локалью (или вообще с [wctomb](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wctomb)), то для кодирования символов Unicode с помощью UTF-8 можно использовать вот такую функцию:

```
// returns utf-8 length (max 4) or 0 if error in ucs
// see https://unicode-table.com/en/
int
ucs_to_utf8 (unsigned int ucs, char *utf)
{
  if (ucs < 128) {
    utf[0] = ucs; // ascii
    return 1;
  }
  int l;

  if (ucs < (1 << 11)) { // 0x80 .. 0x7ff  "Latin-1 Supplement" ... cyrillic ... NKo (africa)
    //  110 xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    l = 1;
    utf[0] = (ucs >> 6) | 0xc0;
  } else if (ucs < (1 << 16)) { // 0x800 ... 0xffff Samaritan ... CJK  ... Specials 
    //  1110 xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    l = 2;
    utf[0] = (ucs >> 12) | 0xe0;
    utf[1] = ((ucs >> 6) & 0x3f) | 0x80;
  } else if (ucs > 0xe01ef) // not defined yet 
    return 0;
  else { // 0x10000 ... 0xe01ef "Linear B Syllabary" ... "CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement" ... 
    // 11110 0xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    l = 3;
    utf[0] = (ucs >> 18) | 0xf0;
    utf[1] = ((ucs >> 12) & 0x3f) | 0x80;
    utf[2] = ((ucs >> 6) & 0x3f) | 0x80;
  }
  utf[l] = (ucs & 0x3f) | 0x80;  // low 6 bits

  return ++l;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Одно из решений - включить в консоли совместимость с кодировкой CP866
Терминал ubuntu это позволяет, собственно это я и сделал
Правда это далеко не смое лучшее решение, т.к. в некторых случаях консоль теперь показывает откровенную дич

Comment: Лучше, все же, выводить в utf-8